# NullPointerException: where's the mistake?

Tags: java, collections

Hi I have to resolve an issue in this program. I don't know why I receive the `NullPointerException`. The program has to read a text file.

```
public class Phone {

private String phone_number;
private String description;

    public Phone(String p_n,String d){

        phone_number=p_n;
        description=d;
    }

    //unrelated getters, setters
}

import java.util.*;

public class Person {

private String surname;
private String name;
private String title;
private String mail_addr;
private String company;
private String position;

private Phone homephone;       
private Phone officephone;      
private Phone cellphone;       

private Collection<Phone> otherphonebooklist;

public Person(String surname,String name,String title,String mail_addr,String company,String position){

    this.surname=surname;
    this.name=name;
    this.title=title;
    this.mail_addr=mail_addr;
    this.company=company;
    this.position=position;

    otherphonebooklist=new ArrayList<Phone>();

}

//unrelated methods

public Collection<Phone> getOtherPhoneBookList(){

    return otherphonebooklist;
}

//unrelated methods
}


import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

/*
* This class rappresent the object 
* list of person
*/

public class PhoneBook { 

private Hashtable<Integer,Person> personList;

public PhoneBook(){

    personList=new Hashtable<Integer,Person>();
}

public void loadPerson(String path) {

       try {

            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path));

            String surname=reader.readLine();

            while(surname!=null){

                String name=reader.readLine();
                String title=reader.readLine();
                String mail_addr=reader.readLine();
                String company=reader.readLine();
                String position=reader.readLine();
                Integer cod_p=Integer.parseInt(reader.readLine());

                Person person = new Person(surname,name,title,mail_addr,company,position); 

                personList.put(cod_p,person);

                surname=reader.readLine();
            }
        }
        catch(FileNotFoundException ffe){
            System.err.println("Error: the person file does not exist");
        }
        catch(IOException ioe){
            ioe.printStackTrace();
        }
}


private void loadNumbers(String numbers){


        try {

            BufferedReader reader= new BufferedReader(new FileReader(numbers));

            String cod_p=reader.readLine();

            while(cod_p!=null){

                String description=reader.readLine();
                String num=reader.readLine();

                Phone phone_number=new Phone(num,description);
                Person p = personList.get(cod_p);

                if(description.equalsIgnoreCase("home phone"))
                    p.setHomePhone(phone_number);
                else if(description.equalsIgnoreCase("office phonne"))
                    p.setOfficePhone(phone_number);
                else if(description.equalsIgnoreCase("cell phone"))
                    p.setCellPhone(phone_number);
                else 
                    p.getOtherPhoneBookList().add(phone_number);

                cod_p=reader.readLine();
            }
        }
        catch(FileNotFoundException ffe){
            System.err.println("Error: the number file does not exist!");
        }
        catch(IOException ioe){
            ioe.printStackTrace();
        }

}

public void load(String p1,String p2){

    loadPerson(p1);
    loadNumbers(p2);
}

//unrelated methods

}
```

When I call in the main the load method I obtain `NullPointerException`. Why?

Here is the stacktrace:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at PhoneBook.loadNumbers(PhoneBook.java:75)
at PhoneBook.load(PhoneBook.java:92)
at ManagementPhoneBook.main(ManagementPhoneBook.java:11)
```

Comment: A bit much code if you ask me, you should have narrowed it down a little. What's the  Stacktrace of the nullpointer exception you get?

Comment: The stacktrace provides a lot of useful information, including which line the error occurs in. Post the stacktrace.

Comment: please, print the stacktrace output and tell us where the error line is!

Comment: Are you unable to make any effort toward narrowing down the problem? Not even a line number?

Comment: (lol 3 same comments in 26 seconds)

Comment: excuse me I forget to insert the printstacktrace...One moment

Comment: btw. where is the main method? It doesn't seem to be included in the code you posted - instead of giving us this big piece of code, the Stacktrace and the actual line where the error occured (i.e. the main method) would have been great!

Comment: Maybe downvoting this question is a little bit harsh. The OP hasn't experience and need a guide. Next time she/he will paste the stack trace or even better, deduce it by her/himself. But until that...

Comment: Since we do not have line numbers in the above code, what is line 75 of PhoneBook?

Comment: 75: p.getOtherPhoneBookList().add(phone_number);

Comment: It's not right.I am a newbie.Everyone has view this post downvote me.

Comment: Not everyone @Mazzy. Click the voting number, you'll see positive vs negative ;-)

Comment: @helios actually, you have to a [1000 rep](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/established-user) to see that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key of personsList (which is a Map not a List) is of type `Integer` which means the key has to be an Integer to find anything.  You are looking up a String which it will never find.

try

```
Person p = personList.get(Integer.parseInt(cod_p));
if (p == null) throw new IllegalStateException("Unable to find "+cod_p);
```

Answer (score 11):

Use a debugger, set a breakpoint at the beginning of the problematic code and then go through your code step by step. The debugger is your best friend.

Comment: +1: Its a shame you can't vote twice.

Comment: I can't agree more.  My life completely changed when I was shown the Eclipse debugging tool...

Answer (score 4):

Putting on my ESP hat I'm going to say that in `loadNumbers()`:

```
 Person p = personList.get(cod_p);
```

This is going to be `null` if that entry isn't in the `HashTable` (BTW, you should be using `HashMap`). You don't check for that, then you try and use `p` which is going to throw the exception.

Comment: I checked through Debubber and I obtain the same thing.I have to understand why

Comment: re: "you should be using HashMap." True. and to be even better, you should replace "private Hashtable<Integer,Person> personList;"
with "private Map<Integer,Person> personList;". This will allow you to change the implementation type of your hashMap (pr HashTable or derivatives) without having to change code everywhere else.

Comment: @Mazzy, You are looking up a key, you haven't loaded into the Map. In the debugger you will be able to see which keys are loaded and which key you are looking up.

Comment: @Mazzy. Of cause, you get the same thing with the debugger, but at least now you know in which code line the error happens and you can inspect the variables. If you do it right, you will see which variable is null and where it leads to an exception.